# What's the most efficient way to toggle a localStorage value with a bookmarklet?

Tags: html, local-storage, bookmarklet

I have a switch that I'd like to turn on and off in my browser's `localStorage` using a bookmarklet.

What would be a good bookmarklet for toggling the value of a hard-coded key between "0" and "1"?

Answer (score 2):

```
javascript:(function(){localStorage["key"]=(localStorage["key"]=="1"?"0":"1")})()
```

Note that the bookmarklet must be run while the browser is on a page in the domain that owns the localStorage value that you'd like to toggle.

Comment: don't forget `void` to prevent the browser rendering the return value